# Checking nulls using if statements vs exception handling

Tags: java

```
String s = foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz().getBaz();
```

I want to return the value of `getBaz()`. The problem is, any of the other methods can possibly return `null` - in which case I want to just return an empty string.

Here is one way of achieving this effect:

```
String s = "";

if (foo.getBar() != null ) {
    if (foo.getBar().getFrobz() != null) {
        if (foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz() != null) {
            if (foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz().getBaz() != null) {
                s = foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz().getBaz();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is another simpler way:

```
String s = "";

try {
    s = foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz().getBaz();
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {

}
```

I've heard exceptions are more expensive than if statements but they do look cleaner. Maybe this issue can be solved another way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you intend to individually handle the intermediate null values in some way?

Comment: Oh god, dat chaining.....

Comment: @cricket_007 No, if there is any null in the chain, I just want to return an empty string.

Comment: Exceptions are more expensive but perhaps that doesn't matter in your case. Is this section performance critical? If not opt for the cleaner code. If it is use the if statements. With Java one generally has to get used to the idea that the code is more verbose and sometimes even repetitive in exchange for being simple, straightforward, type-safe, and efficient.

Comment: @AlexHall I understand what you're saying. I was also considering the possibility that there is maybe another overarching problem that's causing this particular problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ogen never use exceptions to control flow. They are meant to handle exceptional situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here is to just use the nested if conditions. There are no other good solutions and it's not a good idea to use exceptions because I'm not trying to handle exceptions here - I'm merely trying to assign a value.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `Optional` class? It was created for this scenario. You can use it like this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(foo.getBar());

if(optional.isPresent()) {
    // do something with the value
}
```

Note that this only works with Java 8. Apart from that using the value `null` is highly discouraged. You better work with `Exception`s if having a `null` value is a problem.

Note that `foo.getBar().getFrobz().getNobz().getBaz()` is called a "train wreck" in terms of clean code. You should avoid exposing the internals of an object like this.

The following program will print "not present":

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        final Optional<String> s = foo.getBar()
                .flatMap(Bar::getFrobz)
                .flatMap(Frobz::getNobz)
                .flatMap(Nobz::getBaz);
        if(s.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("present");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not present");
        }
    }

    private static class Foo {
        Bar bar;

        public Optional<Bar> getBar() {
            return ofNullable(bar);
        }
    }

    private static class Bar {
        Frobz frobz;

        public Optional<Frobz> getFrobz() {
            return ofNullable(frobz);
        }
    }

    private static class Frobz {
        Nobz nobz;

        public Optional<Nobz> getNobz() {
            return ofNullable(nobz);
        }
    }

    private static class Nobz {
        String baz;

        public Optional<String> getBaz() {
            return ofNullable(baz);
        }
    }
}
```

There is also the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) which can be handy in this kind of situations.

Comment: He can use all the functions provided by `Optional` like `map`, `orElse`, `filter`, etc. This way `Optional` can be used like a monad in Haskell.

Comment: In order for my code to work with an external system I'm interacting with, it needs to be a java.lang.String object unfortunately. Also, this chaining will be in a method exposed to the user called `getBaz()` so they won't see the internals.

Comment: So that's why you downvoted? This answers your question. Apart from `getBaz` all other methods can return `Optional`.

Comment: That just looks painfully complicated.

Comment: Someone was so funny and downvoted all answers with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd want to avoid the chain and make it the responsibility of each caller to give me back a sensible return value that I can then use in a single method.

So, I would call your method as thus:

```
foo.getBar();
```

...and inside `bar`, I would have logic to deal with the scenario of the dependent method coming back as `null`:

```
public String getBar() {
    String result = getFrobz();
    return result == null ? "" : result;
}
```

Of course, this leads to a different kind of chain, but this gives you finer grained control over what each return value should be as opposed to praying that one of the return results you get isn't `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that I think is a little more elegant:

```
Bar bar;
Frobz frobz;
Nobz nobz;
String baz;
if (null != (bar = foo.getBar()) &&
    null != (frobz = bar.getFrobz()) &&
    null != (nobz = frobz.getNobz()) &&
    null != (baz = nobz.getBaz())) {
    s = baz;
}
```

Comment: Wow there's a lot of downvotes going around. What was wrong with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise complete solution based on that of Adam Arold:

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(foo.getBar())
        .map(Bar::getFrobz)
        .map(Frobz::getNobz)
        .map(Nobz::getBaz)
        .orElse("");
```

Comment: @AdamArold see above

Answer (score -2):

It's important to note that the two blocks above are not equivalent. The exception handling will catch NPE thrown *by* the getters *and* NPE thrown by invoking a method in your chain on a null result where as the nested ifs only handle the latter.

Since they do different things, they serve different use cases. Catch the exception only if you want an empty string no matter where the NPE comes from otherwise use the nested if's. The others have offered you ways to reduce deep nesting.